# Define list length in recursion in Coq Not sure if my function is wrong and got stuck

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

So i was trying to define a tail-recursive version of list length function and prove that the function is the same as "length" function
Below is my code. Got stuck when prove

```
Fixpoint length_tail (A: Type) (l: list A) (len: nat): nat :=
  match l, len with
  | [], len => len
  | _ :: t, len => length_tail _ t (1 + len)
end.

Example length_rev: forall {A: Type} {l1: list A}, 
  @length_tail _ l1 0 = @length _ l1.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l1.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl.
    rewrite <- IHl1.
    + simpl.
Admitted.
```

Below is the original function for the "length":

```
Fixpoint length (l:natlist) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => O
  | h :: t => S (length t)
  end.
```

Tons of appreciations if anyone could help or give some hints!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

First, you pattern-match on both `l` and `len` the accumulator in your function but you are not looking at its shape, the following would do just as well:

```
Fixpoint length_tail (A: Type) (l: list A) (len: nat): nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => len
  | _ :: t => length_tail _ t (1 + len)
  end.
```

Second, the problem you are facing is that the lemma you want to prove by induction is not general enough. Indeed you are assuming that the accumulator is `0`, but as you can see in the recursive call, you have `1 + len` (which is just `S len` by the way), which will never be equal to `0`.

In order to prove this by induction you need to prove something *stronger*.
Typically you want to give an expression that is equal to `length_tail l len` in terms of `length l` such that when instantiated with `0` you get `length l`.

To me it sounds like `length_tail l len = len + length l` is a good candidate.
You will have to do this often when proving properties about functions with accumulators.

There are several ways to go about this:

- You could directly prove the more general lemma and then have a corollary, it could be useful for other things.
- You can use `assert` of the stronger lemma in your proof and then conclude with it.
- Or you can `generalize` your goal in your proof. I would personally not use it but I will show it to illustrate what one can do.

```
Fixpoint length_tail {A : Type} (l: list A) (len: nat): nat :=
  match l, len with
  | [], len => len
  | _ :: t, len => length_tail t (1 + len)
end.

Example length_rev : forall {A: Type} {l : list A},
  length_tail l 0 = length l.
Proof.
  intros A l.
  change (length l) with (0 + length l).
  generalize 0 as n.
  (* Now the goal is forall n : nat, length_tail l n = n + length l *)
```

Note that I marked the type as implicit in `length_tail`, this way it's much more readable don't you think?

Comment: Hello Theo I will try this! It is a much more clear RN. Thank you so much for your help!! I don't have any reputation to be able to upvote you But if I can I will give you hundred upvotes. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I think you can still mark the question as accepted if you want. This will help others in knowing you are no longer looking for help on this one.